# Use two submit button in vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have one program where user fill details and below i put one is submit button and another one is know your risk. Now i want when a user click on know your risk account are also created and user go to another page. Submit button are working perfectly. I try many methods but not working. How can i do this.

```
<form
          @submit.prevent="member_whitelist_signup"
          class="login100-form validate-form"
        >
  <div
              class="wrap-login100-form-btn"
              style="z-index: 0"
              
            >

              <div class="login100-form-bgbtn"></div>
              <button class="login100-form-btn">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          

          <CongratsModel v-show="showModal" @close-modal="showModal = false" />
          <div class="container-login100-form-btn m-t-10 m-b-10">
            <p
              
              class="know_your_risk_label text-secondary"
            >
              <button class="login100-form-btn know-risk-text">Know your risk</button>
            </p>
          </div>
```

I put same class on know your rish button but not working

```
self.$http
        .post(self.$member_whitelist_signup, form_data)
        .then(function (response) {
          if (response.data.success == true) {
            if (self.know_your_risk_value == 0) {
              self.user_msg = "Member details updated successfully.";
              localStorage.setItem("new_user", "true");
              self.login_user();
              // self.$router.push({ path: '/member/member-questionnaire' });

            } else {
              // self.showModal=true
              window.location.href = window.location.origin + "/questionnaire";

            }
          } else {
            if (response.data.data == null) {
              self.error_msg = response.data.message;
            } else {
              let first_error_key = Object.keys(response.data.data)[0];
              self.error_msg = response.data.data[first_error_key][0];
            }
          }

          self.devloader = false;
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
          console.warn(error);
        });
```

Comment: What exactly is not working? What happens?

Comment: know your more button not create account and not go to url that i write

Answer (score 0):

#### It's not the class, but the @submit that matters

The class just changes the appearance of the button. You want to change the behaviour.

Try adding this to the Know Your Risk button:

```
@submit.prevent="member_whitelist_signup"
```

Comment: Remember to mark as correct, please! 8-)